# Python cursor notice postgres reset

Tags: python, postgresql, logging, stored-procedures

It's possible to reset Notice by postgresql for each call at stored procedure?

That's my code:

```
.....
connection = db.engine.raw_connection()
connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cursor = connection.cursor()

for i, quarter in enumerate(propQuarters):
  
    cursor.execute(
        "CALL PUBLIC.LOADDATA('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(quarter, prevQuarter, q1Year, dateElab))
    
    for notice in connection.notices:
        logger.info(notice)
```

In this way it also writes previous results-notice in the logs.

I tried to close connection at the end of each loop and reopen on start, but logger.info(notice) report always the previous each output of stored procedure.

Thank you.